# Replace range of matrix with 0 by row

Tags: r, matrix

I wish to replace portions of each row of a `matrix` with `0`.  The portions inside a specified range are to be kept.  The specified range to be kept varies among rows.  I can do this with nested `for-loops`.

However, I think there must be a simple way perhaps using an `apply` statement.

Here is an example with the nested `for-loop` solution.

```
my.matrix <- matrix(c( -5, -4, -3, -2, -1,
                       -2, -1,  0,  1,  2,
                        0,  1,  2,  3,  4,
                       -3, -2, -1,  0,  1), nrow = 4, byrow = TRUE)

# range to retain specified by the following two vectors
first.position <- c(2, 3, 2,  1)
last.position  <- c(4, 5, 5,  1)

# desired result
desired.result <- matrix(c(  0, -4, -3, -2,  0,
                             0,  0,  0,  1,  2,
                             0,  1,  2,  3,  4,
                            -3,  0,  0,  0,  0), nrow = nrow(my.matrix), byrow = TRUE)

new.matrix <- matrix(0, nrow = nrow(my.matrix), ncol = ncol(my.matrix))

# solution using loops
for(i in 1:nrow(my.matrix)) {
     for(j in 1:ncol(my.matrix)) {

          if(j >= first.position[i] & j <= last.position[i]) new.matrix[i,j] = my.matrix[i,j]

     }
}

all.equal(new.matrix, desired.result)
# [1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
my.matrix[
  t(sapply(1:nrow(my.matrix), function(i)
    !(1:ncol(my.matrix) %in% first.position[i]:last.position[i])
  ))] <- 0
```

sapply bit creates TRUE/FALSE matrix with the same nrow and ncol as my.matrix, to which then we assign zero.

Answer (score 2):

For example,

```
# Produce a matrix with indices where my.matrix elements should be kept
L <- mapply(seq,first.position,last.position)
L2 <- sapply(1:length(L),function(i) cbind(i,L[[i]]))
z <- do.call(rbind,L2)

# create a helper matrix m2 and fill it with zeroes
m2 <- my.matrix*0
# set the protected elements to 1 and multiple element-wise with the original matrix
m2[z] <- 1
result <- m2*my.matrix

#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#[1,]    0   -4   -3   -2    0
#[2,]    0    0    0    1    2
#[3,]    0    1    2    3    4
#[4,]   -3    0    0    0    0
```

Comment: An exactly same approach to avoid some looping and operations could be: `n = last.position - first.position + 1; ij = cbind(rep(seq_len(nrow(my.matrix)), n), sequence(n) + rep(first.position, n) - 1); new.matrix = matrix(0, nrow = nrow(my.matrix), ncol = ncol(my.matrix)); new.matrix[ij] = my.matrix[ij]`

Comment: @alexis_laz, nice one. Or, one can do: `m <- t(my.matrix); k <- (seq_along(first.position)-1)*ncol(m); m[-unlist(mapply(seq,first.position+k,last.position+k))] <- 0; result <- t(m)`

Answer (score 2):

Another option to reduce the nested loop to a single loop:

```
new.matrix <- my.matrix
index <- Map(`:`, first.position, last.position)
for(i in 1:nrow(my.matrix)) {
    new.matrix[i,-index[[i]]] <- 0
}
new.matrix
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    0   -4   -3   -2    0
[2,]    0    0    0    1    2
[3,]    0    1    2    3    4
[4,]   -3    0    0    0    0
> identical(new.matrix, desired.result)
[1] TRUE
```